# Where's the Launcher in 12.10?

Tags: launcher

I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop via USB key nicely, but I don't see the Launcher?  Am I missing something here?  How is this possible?  This OS is useless without Firefox or a web browser!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try holding down the super (windows) key.

Comment: oh wow... I didn't know about that.  But it doesn't bring back the launcher like how 12.04 did.